# Team Member - Xcode Configuration Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

A customer of mine has created a new App-Id with an explicit ID.
 
Then he added me as a developer to his organization in iTunesConnect.
 
He has a previous and old version of the app, on which I have to start my work. When I try to create a Provisioning File for my Personal Team (I've not paid the developer program) in Xcode regarding the explicit bundle id created by my customer, *xCode raises the following error message*:

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.xxxx.yyyy' is not available. Please
>   enter a different string.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Because the appID has already been registered by your customer on his provisioning portal

Comment: Customer should add you in developer portal also as a team agent. Then you can add certificate & create provisioning profile in the account.

Comment: Ok, but I will able to add certificate and create provisioning profile also if I'm not enrolled in the Dev Program?

Comment: Yes, by using client's credentials, you can make new certificates and profiles which has already that Bundle identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Apple only allows an app ID to be created by one developer account.  Because your client already has that application ID, you cannot create another one.  If Apple allowed this, you would have app ID conflicts with multiple developers trying to submit apps that have the same app ID.

What you should do is create your developer certificate under the client's organization account, then have your client add your certificate to their provisioning profile.  Then you can download and use this provisioning profile to test the app on devices.  Or, if you are on XCode 7 or later, you should be able to create your own developement provisioning profile with your devices under that team account.  The key is that you need to be doing everything under the client's Team account, not your personal account.

I would not recommend your client share his credentials or make you a team agent.  That's granting you too much power / control as a developer and if I were you, I wouldn't want it.  I would hate to have that access if someone else went in an did something like revoking their certificate, because I know they'd be suspecting me even if I didn't do it.  Use the apple developer account roles the way they were intended and you should be fine.

Comment: could you please clarify this: "you should be able to create your own developement provisioning profile with your devices under that team account"? What does "that team" refer to? And are any steps required to enable you to create your own development provisioning profile under that team account? Thanks

Comment: If your client added you as a team member, when you log into your developer account at the member center at developer.apple.com, it should prompt you to select a team.  Choose the team for your client's account.  If you are creating your provisioning profile on the site, you should now be able to choose the existing app ID when creating the profile.

Comment: If you have your account set up in Xcode, you should be able to do it by selecting the client's team in the Team droupdown under your project settings, as shown here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Art/3_assignteam_ios_2x.png